# How to use awk script to run through a textfile

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

I need to run through a textfile, `doctors.txt`, which is written in the format:

```
Sarah,Jenny,Charles;Dr. Hampton
Jenny,Lucy,Harry;Dr. Fritz
Ben,Kaitlyn,Connor,Charles;Dr. Hampton
```

and have it output:

```
Dr. Hampton: Sarah Jenny Charles Ben Kaitlyn Connor
Dr. Fritz: Jenny Lucy Harry
```

(if someone is mentioned more than once I can't have them repeat)

I need to do this using awk, I currently am having issues even trying to make it print anything:

My code is:

```
 #!/user/bin/awk -f
awk 'BEGIN {for i in $(doctors.txt) {
split(i,doctors,";");}
END{print doctors[1]}'
```

When I run it, I get

```
awk: 3: unexpected character '''
awk: 5: unexpected character '''
```

Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `awk`

```
awk -F\; '{gsub(/,/," ");a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2]" "$1:$1} END {for (i in a) print i": "a[i]}' doctors.txt
Dr. Fritz: Jenny Lucy Harry
Dr. Hampton: Sarah Jenny Charles Ben Kaitlyn Connor Charles
```

To use it in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F\; '{gsub(/,/," ");a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2]" "$1:$1} END {for (i in a) print i": "a[i]}' doctors.txt > doctors2.txt
```

How does it work:

```
a[$2]=      # give array a[$2] the following value
a[$2]       # test if array a[$2] have data already
?           # If yes then
a[$2]" "$1  # add $1 to the variable already stored there
:           # If no the
$1          " just sett array a[$2] to value in $1
```

This part `a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2]" "$1:$1` can be replaced by

```
if (a[$2]) a[$2]=a[$2]" "$1; else a[$2]=$1
```

---

Can be shorten some: (do not need the test, since the extra space is ok)

```
awk -F\; '{gsub(/,/," ");a[$2]=a[$2]" "$1} END {for (i in a) print i":"a[i]}' doctors.txt
```

Comment: When I run this, I get 


awk: 2: unexpected character '\'


awk: 3: unexpected character '''

Comment: This runs fine on Ubuntu, what system are you on?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. How can I put this in a script? Also, what I get when I run this is along the lines of:

Dr. Fritz:
Dr. Hampton:

Comment: I am on Ubuntu @Jotne

Comment: Se my updated post. It will save it to a new file, called `doctors2.txt`

Comment: Nevermind! I was trying to type it myself. Also, thank you so much! @Jotne

Comment: @Jotne, could you explain what this `a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2]" "$1:$1` means?

Comment: Oh, so I thought I had to start it with #!/usr/bin/awk -f as an awk script @Jotne

Comment: See my updated post. `#!/usr/bin/awk` is used when you have an external file with script for `awk`, here is all in one line.

Comment: If I need it to be an external file with awk script, what do I change then? @Jotne

Comment: @boop  Just copy the two line in with the `bash` line to a file with name like this `myscript.sh`, make it executable `chmod 755 myscript.sh` run it like this (if you are in same folder) `./myscript.sh`

Comment: My problem is I need to start it with #!/usr/bin/awk, but that makes it no longer work and I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Oops I forgot to tag you @Jotne

Comment: @boop You do not need `#!/usr/bin/awk` If you give more information of what your are doing, we can help you.  You are trying to create an   `awk` script `awk -f script`. If you put all code after `awk` like this: `awk 'code'` You need `#!/bin/bash` to run bash script.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use perl for this:

```
perl -F";" -lane '@a=split /,/,$F[0];
                  $x{$F[1]}.="@a";
                  END{print "$_:$x{$_}" for(keys %x)}' your_file
```

Tested [here](http://ideone.com/523O3G)

If you insist on awk:

```
awk -F';' '{
           gsub(/,/," ",$1);
           a[$2]=a[$2]""$1}
           END{for(i in a)print i":"a[i]
           }' yourfile
```

Tested the awk version [here](http://ideone.com/7smeuE)

Comment: You miss some spaces with your post.  After `:` here `Dr. Hampton:` and between group of data, so you get `CharlesBen` and not `Charles Ben`

Comment: You have an error here: `print i"":a[i]` should be `print i":"a[i]`.  And this `gsub(/,/,/ /,$1);` should be `gsub(/,/," ",$1);` or just `gsub(/,/," ")` (no `;` and no `$1`)

Comment: @jotne, Thanks and the awk code is fixed . I just did not test the awk version.

Comment: @Vijay If I run this awk script, nothing comes out.

Comment: What do you mean norhing comes out. I have pasted the link, where I have tested the awk version as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -F ";" '{print $1}' doctors.txt
```

Comment: When I run this, it still says unexpected character ''' for the apostrophs around print $1, do you know what is going on? @rjhdby

Comment: You should never use `cat` with `awk`. It can read data itself: `awk 'code'  file.txt` And this answer is not what OP like to get.

Comment: Show full output please. From entering command string *cat doctors.txt | awk -F ";" '{print $1}'*

Comment: awk: 2: unexpected character '.'

awk: 2: unexpected character '''
@rjhdby

Comment: @rjhdby If you see, my post, you see one way to do it, this is not correct.

Comment: Sometimes using cat with awk is are best way for debugging. Not in this case, but not crime

Comment: OP like to sort the doctors that has the same name in one line. Your code does not print the doctors at all.  The `cat` ok for debug, yes, but for other to read, post it correctly.

Comment: I not correctly understood what boop is wanting. But interesting that error appears even in simple awk start